# How to trim N characters from last through batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am reading a text file (input.txt) line by line.
(For this, I am using for-loop)

Inside for loop, I am storing each line in a variable.

After storing line in a variable, I want to trim N characters from last from the variable and need to use it for my own purpose.

But I am not able to trim last N(N=4) characters :-(.

**Example:**

*input.txt* looks like this:

> c:\aaa\bbb\ccc\...
>
> c:\111\222\333\...

**Script:**

```
 @echo off

 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 set Counter=1

 for /f %%x in (Input.txt) do (

   set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"

   set /a Counter+=1

 )

 set /a NumLines=Counter - 1



 for /l %%x in (1,1,%NumLines%) do (

 set trimLast4Char=!Line_%%x!

 echo %trimLast4Char:~0,-4%

 )
```

**Output I am getting:**

~0,-4

~0,-4

**Output I want:**

c:\aaa\bbb\ccc

c:\111\222\333

Comment: try with `echo !trimLast4Char:~0,-4!`

Comment: thanks, it worked :)

Comment: There is a lot easier way to do this if you are working with file paths. You can use the for variable modifiers. Open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?` to read about it.  Your input example looks the same as your output example so I am not quite sure what you are trying to trim but I can almost guarantee that the code will be shorter if all you are trying to do is trim off part of the file path.